# My website is built on Java Server Pages (JSP) - can I use Joomla still?

Tags: java, php, jsp, content-management-system, joomla

My website is built on `JSP` and `Java Servlets`. Html, Javascript and CSS (limited) is contained within my JSP pages as well.

I recently started looking into `Joomla`. I have quite a bit to learn yet...

I understand that Joomla is based on `PHP`.

**[** I don't know anything about PHP, but I've read that knowing PHP is not really necessary in order to use Joomla. **Do you agree?** ]

**I have some questions about Joomla -**

1) The code that Joomla generates, is that in PHP? or Html? Perhaps a combination of both?

2) How, if possible, can I integrate my JSP code into what Joomla generates? 
  
   -- or do I need to integrate the Joomla code into my JSP code?

I have a fully functional website designed in JSP and Java - but after seeing the layout/design that can be accomplished with a CMS, such as Joomla, I want to know how I can 'convert' my site, or 'integrate' it, and still keep it running under JSP and Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joomla is written in PHP. It generates the HTML files which are output to the browser. As far as I know, you'll need PHP to use Joomla unless there's been some sort of JSP port for it (which is highly unlikely).

Simply, Joomla **IS** PHP, and it generates HTML code which the browser reads.

Also, a CMS has nothing to do with layout/design, a CMS is simply that, a **Content Management System**. They are usually designed to be used as the actual website itself, the user just picks a theme and inserts content.

Comment: I suppose the 'themes' for the look of the site are designed in...php?...or is that done with graphics?

Comment: I'm not sure as I haven't used joomla much, but with most CMS', themes are usually a single .php or .html template file which all generated pages will be based on, which links in all the assets such as images, css, js .etc

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to keep the server-side business based on JSP, JAVA and upgrade the layout using Joomla you are facing a lot of PHP programming and the result would not be great in terms of performance. It is easier to migrate to a solution based on JSF and Facelets.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla is written in PHP ans as with every other server side webbased view/template technology (including JSP), it just generates HTML/CSS/JS (a webbrowser doesn't understand anything else anyway).

If the sole requirement is to have a webbased blog engine with a CMS in Java/Servlet, then checkout [Hippo](http://www.onehippo.com/). It's similar to Wordpress/Joomla (although less eye-candy imo).

Answer (score 0):

You could check out Quercus from Caucho which allows you to run PHP applications in a servlet container. I believe they support Joomla though I'm not sure which versions.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution or answer is that you will need complete **rewriting**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Joomla for the web content and JSP for the front end of an enterprise application. Integrating external content in Joomla can be done in many ways, for example, you can embed pages in Menu items, AJAX calls to retrieve content from your JSP pages -either in html or in another format (JSON or XML).